# 404 error on deploying Next.js app with GitHub Actions

Tags: reactjs, next.js, github-pages

I'm  currently trying to deploy a Next.js app on GitHub Pages using GitHub Actions, but I get a page 404 error even after it successfully deploys. I've looked around a bunch of similarly named questions and am having trouble figuring this out.

Here is my GitHub repo: https://github.com/Mctripp10/mctripp10.github.io

Here is my website: https://mctripp10.github.io

I used the *Deploy Next.js site to Pages* workflow that GitHub provides. Here is the `nextjs.yml` file:

```yaml
# Sample workflow for building and deploying a Next.js site to GitHub Pages
#
# To get started with Next.js see: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started
#
name: Deploy Next.js site to Pages

on:
  # Runs on pushes targeting the default branch
  push:
    branches: ["dev"]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# Sets permissions of the GITHUB_TOKEN to allow deployment to GitHub Pages
permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

# Allow only one concurrent deployment, skipping runs queued between the run in-progress and latest queued.
# However, do NOT cancel in-progress runs as we want to allow these production deployments to complete.
concurrency:
  group: "pages"
  cancel-in-progress: false

jobs:
  # Build job
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Detect package manager
        id: detect-package-manager
        run: |
          if [ -f "${{ github.workspace }}/yarn.lock" ]; then
            echo "manager=yarn" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "command=install" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "runner=yarn" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            exit 0
          elif [ -f "${{ github.workspace }}/package.json" ]; then
            echo "manager=npm" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "command=ci" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "runner=npx --no-install" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            exit 0
          else
            echo "Unable to determine package manager"
            exit 1
          fi
      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: "20"
          cache: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.manager }}
      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v4
        with:
          # Automatically inject basePath in your Next.js configuration file and disable
          # server side image optimization (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#unoptimized).
          #
          # You may remove this line if you want to manage the configuration yourself.
          static_site_generator: next
      - name: Restore cache
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: |
            .next/cache
          # Generate a new cache whenever packages or source files change.
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-nextjs-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json', '**/yarn.lock') }}-${{ hashFiles('**.[jt]s', '**.[jt]sx') }}
          # If source files changed but packages didn't, rebuild from a prior cache.
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-nextjs-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json', '**/yarn.lock') }}-
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.manager }} ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.command }}
      - name: Build with Next.js
        run: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.runner }} next build
      - name: Static HTML export with Next.js
        run: ${{ steps.detect-package-manager.outputs.runner }} next export
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v3
        with:
          path: ./out

  # Deployment job
  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v4
```

I got this on the build step:

```
Route (app)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /_not-found                          875 B          81.5 kB
├ ○ /pages/about                         2.16 kB        90.2 kB
├ ○ /pages/contact                       2.6 kB         92.5 kB
├ ○ /pages/experience                    2.25 kB        90.3 kB
├ ○ /pages/home                          2.02 kB          92 kB
└ ○ /pages/projects                      2.16 kB        90.2 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all            80.6 kB
  ├ chunks/472-0de5c8744346f427.js       27.6 kB
  ├ chunks/fd9d1056-138526ba479eb04f.js  51.1 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-4a98b3a5cbccbbdb.js  230 B
  └ chunks/webpack-ea848c4dc35e9b86.js   1.73 kB


○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
```

Full image: [Build with Next.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSlPq.png)

I read in [Next.js pages end in 404 on production build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58039214/next-js-pages-end-in-404-on-production-build) that perhaps it has something to do with having sub-folders inside the `pages` folder, but I'm not sure how to fix that as I wasn't able to get it to work without sub-foldering `page.js` files for each page.

EDIT: Here is my `next.config.js` file:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    basePath: '/pages',
    output: 'export',
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Comment: Can you build the whole app locally and please tell me what's the name of your output directory? There is a possibility that the app gets built, but the bundle is not uploaded to the CDN you are using

Comment: Yes - when I build it locally with `npm run build`, it creates a folder called `out` at the root level of my app and this is where everything is being output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is working and deploying properly, the only thing you are missing is a home route `page.js` to be in `app/page.js`, that is why you get a 404 on the `/` route.

Check this link it is working: https://mctripp10.github.io/pages/home

But your current "home page is nested under `/pages`. I suggest fully removing the `/pages` route to get the desired behavior, also you need to modify your paths not to lead to `/pages/about`, just to use `/about` for example.

Your `app` directory should look like this

```js
//...root project ^

/app
  page.js  // <- your page.js from /pages/home should be here
  layout.js // <- all of your pages will use this layout
  /about // <- when deployed renders https://<<your.url>>/about
   page.js

//... root project v
```

Next will route match pages and render them only if they are located in the `app` directory.

Comment: I moved `page.js` out of `/pages/home` and into `/pages`, but I still got a 404 error. I then tried putting it in the root directory and calling it `index.js` but also got a 404 error. When building locally, I can't get the app to run if there is not a page.js file in /pages/home because that is the path it is looking for when I load up localhost. What am I missing?

Comment: If you move out `page.js` from `/pages/home` you have to remove the route `/pages/home` all together.  In your `next.cofig.js` your base path should be `/`. Try to restructure your project to follow this structure https://blog.coffeeinc.in/how-to-create-a-next-js-13-project-without-using-create-next-app-c73ba6849916 , I will update my answer.

Comment: Adding `page.js` in your root directory won't build the page and it will not work

Comment: That link was helpful as well as your question updates. I understand better now and was able to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using App router, You should follow it's routing structure as well. You Should have a `page.js` inside the `app` folder which will be rendered on `/` route. I also suggest you to follow folder structure as below.

```
app
  page.js
  layout.js
  about (folder)
    page.js
  contact (folder)
    page.js
  ...
components
  Navbar.jsx
  ...
```

Refer [Next.Js Routing Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing#component-hierarchy) for more info

Comment: I put the page.js file under the `app` folder like you showed but I am still getting the 404 error. It won't build locally either as it goes straight to `http://localhost:3000/pages/home` when I open it. Is there something I need to change in config or some other setting?

Comment: sent you a PR on Github

Comment: This is great - just merged the PR. I gave the answer to mssp though for his explanation.